# How to make text from an input appear in another space as user goes typing on it?

Tags: wordpress, bbcode

I have a Wordpress contact form and it does NOT accept HTML/JavaScript content, but only a sort of BBCode like this:

```
[contact-form]
 [contact-field label="Name" type="name" required="1"/]
 [contact-field label="E-mail" type="email" required="1"/]
 [contact-field label="Website" type="url"/]
 [contact-field label="Comment" type="textarea" required="1"/]
[/contact-form]
```

My goal is [do the same as this](https://jsbin.com/yacenuw/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: It seems you already have the JS code required to implement this functionality, and a form too. What's keeping you from doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the bbcode form will get converted into raw html form as output, you can track the id of the field by inspecting the element from browser. 
You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/ for adding custom javascript into your site.

For example you have an output like this from the bbcode type form:

```
<div class='chatbox' id='chatbox'></div>
<input type='text' name='name' class='chatinput' id='chatinput'>
```

You can add some simple JavaScript code to get the job done:

```
var input = document.getElementById('chatinput');
input.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is not able to use own JS. I have a simple solution.

1.Write your js code in a separate file.
2.Upload your file inside your root folder.
3.Find and open header.php file and paste the path to your js file, make sure it is inside your head section. Something like this

```
<script src="../path/to/your/file.js"></script>
</head>
```

Note: header.php can be found from your wp-admin dashboard-->appearance-->editor